# Correct way to make GET and POST requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, get

I want to be able to write a review and display all written reviews (which is none at the moment since the page isn't built yet). It's my first time doing a project like this and I can't get it to work.

**App.js**. I want `const fetchReviews` to GET and display all reviews that has been written and I want `const postReview` to simply post a new review to the page.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

import { NewReview } from "./NewReview.js";
import { AllReviews } from "./AllReviews";

const reviewsURL = "http://localhost:8080/reviews"

export const App = () => {
  const [existingReviews, setExistingReviews] = useState([])
  const [newReview, setNewReview] = useState('')

  const fetchReviews = () => {
    fetch(reviewsURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setExistingReviews(reviews)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchReviews();
  }, []);


  const postReview = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(reviewsURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({message: newReview})
    })
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (() => {
      fetchReviews();
      setNewReview('')
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
  }
  return (
    <>

<NewReview
      newReview={newReview}
      setNewReview={setNewReview}
      handlesubmit={postReview}
      />

{<AllReviews 
        allReviews={existingReviews} 
        />}
    </>
  )
}
```

**Index.js** will act as my server, I'm using localhost. I will not use mongo/mongoose.

I have tried many different things now for the past two weeks, read a bunch of questions and answers on Stack, I've tried import(), require(), update json package but I am so stuck. Which makes me wonder if the import and usage of `AllReviews` and `NewReviews` is even close to being  correct?

Please help, I have spent so many hours on this.

```
import express from 'express'

import { NewReview } from '../frontend/src/NewReview.js';
import { AllReviews } from '../frontend/src/AllReviews.js';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
  });

// GET all reviews
app.get("/reviews", (request, response) => {
  response.status(201).json(AllReviews)
});

  //POST a new review
  app.post('/reviews', async (request, response) => {
    try {
      response.status(201).json(NewReview)
    } 
      catch (err) {
      response.status(400).json({ message: 'Sorry, could not save review to the database', errors: err.errors
      })
    }
  })



app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**NewReview.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const NewReview = ({newReview, setNewReview, handleSubmit}) => {
    return(
        <section className="newReviewContainer">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    <textarea
                    placeholder="Write your review here"
                    rows="3"
                    onChange={event => setNewReview(event.target.value)}
                    value={newReview}>
                    </textarea>
                </label>

                <button className="sendReview"
                type="submit">
                    <p>SEND REVIEW</p>
                </button>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you get the response message when you go to `localhost:8080/`?

Comment: I can't even open localhost, the terminal keeps telling me things are wrong. I've read about the errors and tried to correct them for two weeks. Now I'm stuck with `''SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` on *<section className* in NewReview.js (attatched the code in the question)...

Comment: You don't need to import your frontend files into your server

Comment: @WebbH oh! That really shows I've got this wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for correcting me. I read now that the tick will appear after 48 hours, I'll mark the question as asked after that.

Comment: The tick is for answers. For the one answer which you found most helpful. You do not have answers. Make one yourself, giving credit to the comment, if that is what you got your answer from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WebbH** commented that I don't need to import my frontend files into my server. So I deleted the part in my server where I tried to import it and that solved my problem.